# After removing an item from a Dictionary, how to change the other keys accordingly?

Tags: c#, dictionary

For example, a dictionary contains,

```
key:   1 2 3 4 5
value: a b c d e
```

Once you delete the item `b`, the dictionary would looks like this,

```
key:   1 3 4 5 
value: a c d e
```

However, I want the key to be like so,

```
key:   1 2 3 4
value: a c d e
```

Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: i think you want a sorted list. a dictionary isn't really for stuff like that.

Comment: A dictionary is a list of pairs of values. What you're asking means not treating them as that. You'll need to create your own collection type.

Comment: I don't know why you need a dictionary. Use a `List<string>` which contains only the values. The keys are just the indexes. So if you remove an item there is one item less, hence one index less. Retrieving the value via index is an O(1) operation; so you have even the same performance as a dictionary.

Comment: How do you plan to manage the adding of new items to the dictionary? If you could describe the root problem more specifically, you will get a better solution. This isn't what a dictionary was built for.

Answer (score 1):

You want an `Array` or a `List`, not a dictionary.

If you want to keep it as a dictionary, you could convert it to a list, then remove the entry, then reconvert it back to a dictionary.

```
var list = new List<string>();
foreach(var item in dictionary)
{
    list.Add(item.Value);
}
var newDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
for(int i = 1; i < list.Count + 1; i++)
{
    newDict.Add(i,list[i]);
}
```

Don't do this though.

Comment: +1 this suggestion is not that bad (see my comment above). However, i'm missing an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is not the right approach. However, it is possible. Here's another way:

```
public static void Test()
{
    var foo = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "a" }, { 2, "b" }, { 3, "c" }, { 4, "d" }, { 5, "e" } };

    RemoveItemByKey(ref foo, 3);
    RemoveItemByValue(ref foo, "a");

    foreach (var kvp in foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }

    // Output:
    // 1: b
    // 2: d
    // 3: e
}

public static void RemoveItemByValue(ref Dictionary<int, string> dictionary, string valueToRemove)
{
    foreach (var kvp in dictionary.Where(item=>item.Value.Equals(valueToRemove)).ToList())
    {
        RemoveItemByKey(ref dictionary, kvp.Key);
    }
}

public static void RemoveItemByKey(ref Dictionary<int, string> dictionary, int keyToRemove)
{           
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(keyToRemove))
    {
        dictionary.Remove(keyToRemove);

        int startIndex = 1;
        dictionary = dictionary.ToDictionary(keyValuePair => startIndex++, keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, you may also need to implement an 'Add item' property that takes a string value to add, so it gets the correct key. Something like `dictionary.Add(dictionary.Count, newValue)`. But if you could describe your problem better, you'll get a better solution!